After specifying a proxy in the genymotion settings, it goes on endlessly Starting virtual device
I downloaded Genymotion, specified a proxy in the settings. Then I clicked start the device. If I use it without proxy everything works correctly, if I use it with proxy it doesn't start correctly
I've tried changing the proxy, reinstalling Genymotion, and running without the proxy. Without the proxy, the emulator works

Are you trying to connect a virtual device to a proxy?
If so, you should not use this settings: the proxy option in Genymotion launchpad is only used to get Genymotion communicating with Genymobile's servers if your whole network is behind a proxy (like a company network).
Instead, follow the steps from this article.
